# Looking for an elegant way of error checking a form

Tags: php

Could someone suggest a more elegant way of checking a form is filled in on submit with php, my way below seems too long winded. I may want other types of checking also for example if QA1 is set to 2 then QA1C should be populated and append an error if it is not.

```
if (empty($_POST['QA1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QA1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QA2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QA2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QA3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QA3 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB3 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB4'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB4 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB5'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB5 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB6'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB6 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB7'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB7 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB8'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB8 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QB9'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QB9 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QC1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QC1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QD1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QD1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QD2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QD2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QD3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QD3 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QE1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QE1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QE2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QE2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QF1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QF1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QF2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QF2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QF3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QF3 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QF4'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QF4 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QF5'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QF5 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QG1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QG1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QG2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QG2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QG3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QG3 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QG4'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QG4 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QH1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QH1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QI1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QI1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QI2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QI2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QJ1'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QJ1 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QJ2'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QJ2 not specified</h1>";}
if (empty($_POST['QJ3'])) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>QJ3 not specified</h1>";}
```

Comment: Use an array and loop through it. You can find a brief explanation at [How do I create arrays in a HTML form?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML form try to name your inputs like **my_form[QG2]** , **my_form[QA1]**, ... 
so in your controller you will handle the my_form as an array and it will be very easy to handle erros as bellow :

```
<?php
    $myforms = $_POST['my_form'];
    foreach ($myforms as $key => $mf) {
    if (empty($mf)) {$errorMessage .= "<h1>$key not specified</h1>";}
    }
```

Comment: This will work but only if there is no other form elements that he wants to validate in a different manner.

Comment: even if there's others, you will just rename the inputs that you want treat by this manner , for others inputs you can use my_second_form[<input_name>], its like a tag !

Comment: Delayed response but this is what I went with, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    // Required field names
    $required = array('QA1', 'QA2', 'QA3', .....);

    // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) {
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = $field;
        break;
      }
    }

    if ($error) {
      echo "All fields are required." . $field;
    } else {
      echo "Proceed...";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be this can help you, but you should exclude other posts variables if you don't need to check

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $post) {
         if(empty($post)) {
             $errorMessage .= "<h1>".$post."not specified</h1>";
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using javascript for your form validations. Ive used validate.js and cant complain
https://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Comment: Then I can just disable my javascript and enter whatever I want. It is always best practice to validate input on both client and server side.

Comment: Client side is for the clients experience. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes i'm using javascript also, thats not particulary elegant either so ill take a look at that